# Google BigQuery Metadata

Tags: google-bigquery, metadata

I am trying to populate populate and collect metadata for the business in GBQ. Basically, the business doesn't have access to tables, we create authorised views for them that they use in their reports. 
The problem is, if I populate the column description field in the table, the views based on that table won't inherit the metadata, the same with sharded tables.
There is going to be a degree of data entry to populate the metadata, but I  would really like to be able to share it across related views.
Is it possible to automate BQ metadata in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some different options to both get information about a table or a view (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#getting_information_about_tables), and to update that information (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-views#update-description).

Depending on your specific case you can use the bq command line or a programming language SDK to automatize the process for retrieving and updating BigQuery's metadata.